# Using processbuilder

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to use ProcessBuilder in order to highlight several files contained in a folder.
When I run the following code:

```
List<String> params = java.util.Arrays.asList("explorer.exe", "/select,C:\\test\\file1.txt", 
                "/select,C:\\test\\file2.txt");
        ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder(params);
```

only the second file is highlighted. Any idea on how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't have a PC at hand, but try listing the files using a single /select parameter, for example "/select,file1,file2"

Comment: Already tried and only file one will be highligthed.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if `explorer.exe` provides options to select multiple files.

Comment: Do you know anything else i could you instead?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
java.util.Arrays.asList("explorer.exe", "/select,C:\\test\\file1.txt", 
  "/select,C:\\test\\file2.txt"
```

try (from the relevant [knowledge base](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457))

```
java.util.Arrays.asList("explorer.exe", "/select,C:\\test\\file1.txt,select,C:\\test\\file2.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work. Only file1 is highligthed.